# Constructor for parametric alias

Tags: generics, julia

I specified a custom `AbstractArray` type with additional generic parameters.
I wanted to make an alias for matrices and use an existing outer constructor,
but stumbled upon such a behaviour:

```
struct MyArray{T,N,K} <: AbstractArray{T,N}
    t::T
end

MyMatrix{T} = MyArray{T,2,1}

MyArray{T,N,K}(x::AbstractArray{T,N}) where {T,N,K} = MyArray{T,N,K}(x[1])

mat = MyMatrix([1 2; 3 4])
```

```
MethodError: no method matching MyArray{T,2,1} where T(::Array{Int64,2})
```

To me, a constructor call with type `MyArray{T,2,1} where T(::Array{Int64,2})` should be able to use
the one already declared.
I had a couple of other outer constructors, but all for the generic `MyArray`
(and apparently not any of the ones that would make the preceding code legal).

If I declare a specific constructor everything works:

```
MyMatrix(x::AbstractMatrix{T}) where {T} = MyMatrix{T}(x[1])
```

but it seems redundant to have constructors for aliases.

Similarly, I can specify the type with the constructor call:

```
mat = MyMatrix{Int}([1 2; 3 4])
```

but here the information is also repeated, as the type can be deduced from the argument.

Is there a way for me not to repeat the types or specialize the constructors when I use the matrix type?

Answer (score 1):

The takeaway message is that `MyMatrix(x)` doesn't know how to infer the parameter `T`. But you can always explicitly define the desired behavior.

---

It takes me a while to understand your question, so correct me if I'm wrong.
Let's say we have only defined the `MyArray` and the alias `MyMatrix`:

```
struct MyArray{T,N,K} <: AbstractArray{T,N}
    t::T
end

MyMatrix{T} = MyArray{T,2,1}
```

Simply call `MyMatrix(0)` will trigger the error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching MyArray{T,2,1} where T(::Int64)
```

I guess that you may assume the type parameter `T` can be inferred to be of `Int64`. Unfortunately not. But you can just define a constructor like this:

```
MyMatrix(x::T) where T = MyMatrix{T}(x)
```

Now the second question is that we have a default constructor for `MyArray`:

```
MyArray{T,N,K}(x::AbstractArray{T,N}) where {T,N,K} = MyArray{T,N,K}(x[1])
```

And you wish that `MyMatrix([1 2; 3 4]) === MyMatrix{Int}(1)`. But in fact, it will only call the method we just defined:

```
julia> @which MyMatrix([1 2; 3 4])
(::Type{MyArray{T,2,1} where T})(x::T) where T in Main at REPL[3]:1
```

So we can define another more specific method (but not that specific like the one you provide ;)

```
MyMatrix(x::AbstractArray{T}) where T = MyMatrix{T}(x)
```

Then it will fall back to your general definition of `MyArray{T,N,K}(x::AbstractArray{T,N}) where {T,N,K} = MyArray{T,N,K}(x[1])`

```
julia> @code_typed MyMatrix([1 2; 3 4])
CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = (Base.arrayref)(true, x, 1)::Int64
│   %2 = %new(MyArray{Int64,2,1}, %1)::MyArray{Int64,2,1}
└──      return %2
) => MyArray{Int64,2,1}
```